# The fastest way to get count of processed dataframe records in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm currently developing a Spark Application that uses dataframes to compute and aggregates specific columns from a hive table.

Aside from using `count()` function in `dataframes/rdd`. Is there a more optimal approach to get the number of records processed or number of count of records of a dataframe ?

I just need to know if there's something needed to override a specific function or so.

Any replies would be appreciated. I'm currently using Apache spark 1.6.

Thank you.

Comment: Using inbuilt function is the optimal approach. Aren't you using dataframe.count() function? If not can you update your question with sample code?

Comment: Well for dataframe you can use `select count(*)` but I don't understand why would you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Aside from using count() function in dataframes/rdd, is there a more optimal 
>   approach to get the number of records processed or number of count of records 
>   of a dataframe?

Nope. Since an RDD may have an arbitrarily complex execution plan, involving JDBC table queries, file scans, etc., there's no apriori way to determine its size short of counting.